# what are the conditions for the product of 2 symmetric matrices being symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In generally, the product of two symmetric matrices is not symmetric, so I am wondering under what conditions the product is symmetric.

Likewise, over complex space, what are the conditions for the product of 2 Hermitian matrices being Hermitian?

Thanks!

Comment: What sort of conditions do are you looking for?

Comment: if they commute, is possibly the simplest condition. 

Comment: If and only if they are commuting...

Comment: Simon's condition is presumably the best possible answer.  Incidentally, the "right" product structure on symmetric matrices is the Jordan product $A \circ B = (AB + BA)/2$, which reduces to the ordinary product if and only if $A$ and $B$ commute.

Comment: This looks like homework

Comment: Voting to close as too localized (and so the site won't kick it back to the front page, as no answer has been accepted).

Comment: I assume Simon thought that the proof of his answer is too trivial to warrant mention, but for what it's worth, if $A$, $B$, and $AB$ are symmetric, then $AB=(AB)^t=B^tA^t=BA$.

Comment: And indeed this has been bumped up. Why wasn't it closed?

Answer (score 4):

Incidentally, every real matrix is the product of two symmetric matrices. (If I remember correctly, I once read about this in a paper by Halmos).

Comment: Right. But not all complex matrices are product of two Hermitian matrices. A necessary and sufficient condition is to be similar to a real matrix.